# wildcard certificate with unnamed sub domain

Tags: wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I have purchased a wildcard subdomain for one of my domain names.  Here is the issue I am running into:

I have a WordPress plugin that integrates with a 3rd party membership site.  The membership site issues a member alias that is interpreted into a subdomain url....example Member "John Doe" get "JohnDoe.domain.com". These subdomains are not redirected, just used as a member identifier by my plugin. I have thousands of members.

***Note***these subdomains are not expressly inserted into my bluehost subdomains listed. There is simply too many subdomains to easily do that.

Should I expect my wildcard cert to still "secure" my "unnamed" subdomains or will I have to expressly write in my subdomains into my hosting service (Bluehost)?

Ultimately I want to have any subdomain, anyone ever creates, to automatically be secured under my domain name with no effort on my part.

Thoughts?

Comment: This would depend on how BlueHost have their systems setup.  You should ask them.

Comment: I have asked them...but each time I do I get a different answer as they seem to be outsourcing their support

Comment: In what context are these subdomain identifiers actually used? It is hard to answer your question without better description of the components.

Comment: The app looks at the subdomain name, reads it and translates it on my site to modify some pre-set merge fields.  It should not affect any of the security components, it was just my backstory for why I don't want to have to manually insert every subdomain into my hosting account